# Call a Composable function from an onClick that is in a Composable

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, android-camerax

I have a page where i have a compose card that has a onClick:

```
Card(
         modifier = Modifier
           .width(cardWidth)
           .height(cardHeight)
           .padding(cardPadding),
           onClick = { Camera.Preview() },
           content = {
              //Code
            }
```

But the problem i have is that i get error: "@Composable invocations can only happen from the context of a @Composable function"
Since Camera.Preview() is a Composable function:

```
object Camera {

@Composable
fun Preview(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    scaleType: PreviewView.ScaleType = PreviewView.ScaleType.FILL_CENTER,
    cameraSelector: CameraSelector = CameraSelector.DEFAULT_BACK_CAMERA
) {
//Code
}
```

how do i call Camera.Preview() from the onClick event without getting this error.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! If you found an answer useful, you can accept it by clicking the checkmark at the left side of the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show a Composable after a click, do it as follows:

```
@Composable
fun MainComposable() {

    var showPreview by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }

    Column(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
    ) {

        if (showPreview) {
            Preview()
        }

        Card(
            modifier = Modifier
                .width(cardWidth)
                .height(cardHeight)
                .padding(cardPadding),
            onClick = { showPreview = true },
            content = {
                //Code
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Once you click on the Card, you will set the `showPreview` variable to true. This will trigger a recomposition, the `if` statement becomes `true`, and the Preview Composable will be shown.

Also, it is not common place Composables into objects, as you are doing right now with the `Camera` object. Just place it as a normal function into the .kt file.

Comment: Thank you this works perfectly and i will get rid of the object, thanks for mentioning that!